# Can't enable focus selector with anchors in css in Safari

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm aware that certain elements can't accept a `focus` selector, such as list elements, but I thought that anchors were fine. Using the following code (I'm creating a pure css responsive drop-down menu), I can't make the hidden `ul` appear when clicking the anchor.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="primarylist">
    <a href="#" class='category1anchor'>Text</a>
    <ul class="menudrop">
      <li class="secondarylist">One</li>
      <li class="secondarylist">Two</li>
      <li class="secondarylist">Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.menudrop {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
li.primarylist a:focus + ul.menudrop {
  display: block;
}
```

**jsFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kx0kex7x/

Change the *jsFiddle* selector from `focus` to `hover`, and it works perfectly, leaving me without any reason to doubt my syntax is correct. Using `active` only displays the `ul` for the duration of the mousedown. Any pointers? (I'm on Safari 10. Seems to work in the latest Chrome and FF fine).

---

### Update

I've tried using the `target` selector with partial success. If I change my `a.categor1anchor` links to match newly created unique ids for each `ul.menudrop`, I can make the `ul.menudrop` appear on clicking the anchor. However, this is a responsive design and I can't seem to remove the `target` selector at other page sizes. For example, at a larger page size, I use the `hover` selector instead, but the last targeted `ul.menudrop` from a smaller screensize remains open at larger screen sizes. I can't see any way to clear target selectors for responsive designs. `Inherit` and `Initial` displays don't affect it.

Comment: Testing on Chrome and FF, your code seems to work just fine

Comment: Silly of me not to test in them before posting. The question still remains as I need it to work in Safari, but I've edited the question to make this clear. Thanks.

Comment: Using focus for this is not ideal. The element will lose focus, as soon as you activate anything else - so even if the user was f.e. tabbing through the links using their keyboard, you menu would disappear again as soon as the user moves focus to the first link. :focus is not really suited to handle more complex UI states. You should perhaps rather looking into using checkboxes and the :checked pseudo class.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. This is for a responsive menu, and this state is only available on phones. What you describe sounds like what I'm aiming for. The menu remains hidden and subsections of it only appear on deliberate selection and disappear if the user selects anything else.

Comment: If that's what you're looking for then maybe this is something you can use and abuse http://codepen.io/villekoo/pen/VejNba

Comment: Yes, you're not wrong with suggesting checkboxes. I've avoided them as I feel they're so awkward and inelegant in styling, as a hack for menus, that I'd rather just use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for the past few days and progressing down multiple avenues only to find a slightly convoluted hack is needed to solve every situation I'll find the menu in, I think it's turning out more elegant and clean to just use `jQuery` alongside my code to handle various dropdowns appearing, etc. I was trying to avoid it but I don't think `CSS` is still quite robust enough for menus of this type at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that anchor tags in Safari need to have tabindex set in order to receive focus.

```css
ul.menudrop {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
li.primarylist a:focus + ul.menudrop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="primarylist">
    <a href="#" class='category1anchor' tabindex="0">Text</a>
    <ul class="menudrop">
      <li class="secondarylist">One</li>
      <li class="secondarylist">Two</li>
      <li class="secondarylist">Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/dhpom1uw/

Comment: I had this set up before but it fell apart when my responsive design changed the aesthetics to something more complex at larger sizes. While it technically worked at larger sizes too, it created an ugly focus bar around the the menu elements when I hovered over them (the larger page sizes changed to responding to the hover selector). It seems like a solution that might work for static and less-fluid layouts.