# Remove css pseudo-class properties without javascript in responsive layout

Tags: html, css

This is a spinoff of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093657/cant-enable-focus-selector-with-anchors-in-css-in-safari?noredirect=1#comment73269465_43093657) but, in a responsive design, is there a way to remove the effect of a pseudo class at certain sizes or media?

In my case, I use `:target` at a small screen size to display a hidden `ul` element when a link is clicked. At larger screen sizes, `:target` is not used anymore and is replaced by `:hover`. However, if any ul element was targeted at small screen sizes, it remains visible at larger screen sizes and destroys the `:hover` navigation.

I want the browser to treat the `display` property of the `ul`, at the larger screen sizes, as if the `:target` pseudo class never existed. Its regular class state is `display:none`, but I can't seem to make it go back to `none` at larger sizes without removing the ability for `:hover` to change it to `block`. For example, specifying that any `:target` `ul` at larger sizes uses `display: none` results in `:hover` having no effect.

It will, of course, work if I change the `display` property of `:hover` to have `!important` added. I've had it beaten into me that this should be avoided wherever possible. I'm also concerned it'll be ignored by some browsers. Is this one of these rare cases where it's warrented?

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/77a82kft/1/

Comment: Can you share you code

Comment: Sounds like you should just wrap your :target-based formatting into appropriate media queries in the first place ...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pseudo-selector". `:target` is a **pseudo-class**.

Comment: torazaburo , thanks, corrected. CBroe , would you be able to elaborate? In my actual code I've placed my entire menu styling inside each size query, leaving nothing shared outside a query. Super User  done, though :hover is doing nothing for me in jsFiddle, despite working ok for me on my actual page. I've clearly overlooked something in jsFiddle - perhaps it relates to the main issue.